# Can I mix JSTL with JavaScript like this?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Can I used JavaScript and JSTL together like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function selectDifferentAccount(select, id){

    if (id == "0"){
        var balance = "sourceBalance";
        <c:set var="sourceBalance" value="${select}" scope="session" /> 
    }
    else if (id == "1"){
        var balance = "targetBalance";
        <c:set var="targetBalance" value="${select}" scope="session" /> 
        document.write(${targetBalance});
    }
}
</script>
```

I want the select argument to be sent to the sessionScope variable used by JSTL but not sure if that is possible since document.write does not print out anything.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ${} EL expression unless variable is in scope.

First server side code is generated and then client side.

So now control comes to Javascript method.
You can set that value as both are different environments.

```
function selectDifferentAccount(select, id){

 if (id == "0"){
    var balance = ${someVariable}; // fine
    <c:set var="sourceBalance" value="${select}" scope="session" />// but not reverse 
 }
```